# How to split special char with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

If have the following string:
`MAC 1 USD14,IPHONE4 1-2-3-4 USD22,USD44,USD66,USD88`

Then I would like to generate the following output:
`1,1,2,3,4`

I am using `(\\bUSD\\d{1,99})(\\bMAC)(\\bIPHONE\\d)` to split it but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: you need single digit integer or multiple?

Comment: @MohanRaj hi, i need single digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `split()`. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to extract strings. It will be easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "MAC 1 USD14,IPHONE4 1-2-3-4 USD22,USD44,USD66,USD88<br>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s|-)\\d(?=\\s|-)"); // extract a single digit preceeded and suceeded by either a space or a `-`
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
1
1
2
3
4
```

Note : `Pattern.compile("\\b\\d\\b");` will also give you the same answer.

EDIT : `(?<=\\s|-)\\d(?=\\s|-)"` :

> (?<=\s|-) --> positive look-behind. Looks for a digit (\d) preceeded
>   by either a space or a - (i.e, dash).
>
> (?=\s|-)  --> positive look-ahead. Looks for a digit (\d) followed
>   by either a space or a - (i.e, dash).

Note that look-behinds / look-aheads are *matched* but not *captured*

Comment: Could you explain the pattern you have used here?